# Stopping an application from allocating memory before it exhausts the Windows (or any OS) page file

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management

I am currently facing a situation where my C++ OpenGL based application deliberately allocates huge amounts memory for resources. In fact, so many that Windows just stops and I get a completely blank screen. Afterwards, I
found out (randomly - Windows didn't even tell me!) that Windows was forced to extend my page file to 30GB.

For applications with potentially large Private Memory usage, but also having the need to run on low memory hardware as well as take advantage of hardware with lots of memory, then some sort of scheme to detect max mem usage (and the appropriate action) must be devised.

In this case, I would of thought we want to ride the fine line between too much allocation to push Windows over the edge, and not enough allocation (causing a bad user experience) so I'm looking for a way to determine the sensible point at which to stop allocating memory within my application in order to protect Windows from itself. From educating myself a little by listening to Mark Russinovich (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjTl53I_qzY), I cant find any sort of rule of thumb.

What, if any, are the best practice measures for an application throttling itself from allocating too much and making Windows (or any OS) constantly swap the pagefile/run out of pagefile space (killing the system)?

Should we just be monitoring the Page File Size and Private Bytes allocated to the process, and literally just stop allocating textures when the Private Bytes grows to some arbitrary percentage or the Page File Size, as a last resort to avoid the system dying? The question then gets pushed to "how do you figure out that point"?

Appreciate any and all help!

Thanks - Laythe

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just, you know, not allocate so much memory? I mean clearly, if you can run on low-memory systems at all, then you must have some way to stop yourself from allocating more and work with what you have. So why not do that to begin with? Or if you need a rule of thumb, don't allocate more memory than actually exists.

Comment: @Nicol - Yes that is the question, at what point do you stop? I want to allocate "as much as possible" to provide the user with a good user experience, but not enough to crash Windows minus another safety amount probably. But there is not just a single number called "free memory" in the OS. There are a number of factors at play here current RAM capacity, OS version maybe (32/64 bit), current private bytes count, working set size, etc, etc.

Comment: @Nicol All of these have non trivial impact on when to stop allocating and was looking for pointers as to what people normally do. Any testing I do on my PC will not likely be optimal on another, so was wondering if the OS can provide an application with "hints" as to absolute MAX to allocate or if not how the application determines it. I know - many wont care.

Comment: Why are you linking allocating memory to "good user experience"? You allocate the memory your application *needs* in order to do its job. You don't allocate memory just because it's there.

Comment: _"You can use the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function to determine how much memory your application can allocate without severely impacting other applications."_  see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Nicol If I can allocate large amounts of memory, then I can display large quantities of data on the screen. Think 3D picture wall. I also want the ability to move from location to location fast, and minimise visual artifacts such as the background loader thread pulling in graphics, and the best way to achieve this is have as much as possible loaded already. Ideally I want to load it all. Obviously this wont work and I have to draw a line *somewhere*. It's just where.

Comment: @Richard Critten Thanks for the link, I will investigate further. It looks like we can get a few stats out of that, although there are a whole load more parameters that may/may not be relevant such as the the process private data usage etc. (things shown on proc explorer). The article didn't mention how those other things relate to the data returned. I guess what I am after is some formula such as MaxRecommendedPrivateBytes = xyz, where x * y / z would be the data returned from functions like GlobalMemoryStatusEx.

Comment: @Laythe: "Where" you draw that line is obvious: you use as little memory as possible. Unless your application is intended to be the primary thing the user uses the machine for at that time, your application should have as its first priority to *not* harm the integrity of the system. So if the user wants to run some other program and switch back and forth, that's their right, and your application should accommodate that.

Comment: @Nicol "your application should have as its first priority to not harm the integrity of the system". Yes this is what I want to happen and therefore need to know when to stop allocating memory. There is no such thing as "little as possible" as it will be up to the user as to how many resources to load, but I want to allow them the maximal amount for their system, *without harming* the system.